# How do you accomplish equipotential bonding for an above ground polyester/PVC pool if the filter pump provided is not compatible?

Tags: grounding-and-bonding

I recently bought a Bestway 15' x 48" above ground "flexible assembly" pool with polyester-type material and PVC-type vertical frame. In Florida,a permit is required for all pools with depth over 42".  The permit includes the requirement to install equipotential bonding to the pool. The pool comes with a simple filter pump which does not facilitate bonding and no skimmer basket is provided with the product. However, I bought a portable skimmer for the pool but the skimmer is of plastic and must be placed inside the pool wall.  I have done an enormous amount of research on the Internet to find products that could work with this type of pool to meet the bonding procedure, without much success.  Hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: This is similar to the problem of needing to attach 3 wires to a receptacle with only 2 screws.  When devices provide facilities for that sort of thing (e.g. 2 screws), that’s a courtesy time-saver alternative to the *normal* way of doing things (e.g. pigtail).  There’s always the normal way.

Comment: When you say "polyester type material" are you referring to a fabric-like material?

Comment: Also, is there a place for a spare "receptacle" near where you plug the pool in at?

Answer (score 1):

### The pump is a red herring

The pump has nothing to do with the equipotential bonding requirement.  So looking at the pump to help you is dead-end.

Your bonding effort should ignore the pump altogether.

### Equipotential bonding is generally done to panels.

Equipotential bonding is just another phrase for the normal “grounding electrodes” that your house already has.  The requirement is that the pool have a separate set of grounding electrodes all its own, and those attach to the house’s grounding electrode system.

So that goes back to your main panel, or if you have a pool subpanel that is connected 4-wire (separate neutral and ground) to the main panel, then it goes there.

The purpose is to keep the earth around your pool from floating at a voltage above safety ground, as this would break/defeat the GFCI devices that protect your family.

Comment: This is a removable, storable, polyester/pvc pool that has no connections to the "house".  It uses only a small 2500 GPH filter pump to circulate and clean 4000 gal of water. (2 hours max). No electricity is required for the pool itself.  There has to be some other way to satisfy the equipotential bonding requirement without getting complicated. I'll continue to research and share any new findings on the subject.  Anyone having success with a similar issue could also chime in.

Comment: BTW: I'll be answering this question roughly mid-September if all goes well as that's when the results on [proposed TIA #1524 to the NEC](https://www.nfpa.org/assets/files/AboutTheCodes/70/Proposed_TIA_1524_NFPA_70.pdf) will be in...

Answer (score 1):

The requirement for equipotential bonding is a real thing!

No it is not about your service.

equipotential Bonding it is all about making all conductive surfaces have a equal potential to ground.

Now the code commentary pools 42” and less do not require 680.26 but you have none of the metallic items that require bonding in your all plastic pool so the only possibility is the ring.

if you have no conductive surfaces there is nothing to bond to.below is a review of the main points with equipotential bonding.

The requirement for the pump is in the cord for a storable (and a double insulated pump GFCI cord 25’ or longer)

So if you have a all plastic pool and frame there is nothing to bond, the bonding of the frame came from the old metal segmented pool frames where 1 bond was not sufficient to bond the entire frame.

Code is quite specific and the only difference is todays plastic frames or lack of a frame
Article 680.26 is all about eliminating voltage gradients
1 conductive shells.

2 perimeter surfaces paved or unpaved (they could require a ground loop here I have not seen it in Oregon)

3 Metallic components, again none here.

4 underwater lighting , I have seen this but it was battery LED’s no grounding required.

5 metal fittings, again all plastic pool no
metal to ground.

6 electrical equipment, the normal portable pool
pumps are used here they require a 25’ cord with an integrated GFCI.

7 fixed metal parts, again no metal so there is nothing to bond.

The only thing you may have to do is install a ground loop but I have never seen this required for a plastic above ground pool.

These are the sections that deal with equipotential bonding all the conductive parts are connected to reduce voltage gradients

Answer (score 1):

### This was a NEC issue, fixed in 2023

NEC editions from the 1980s through 2020 set an arbitrary 42" cutoff on the depth of storable pools.  This proved to be unworkable due to advances that permitted deeper storable pools (like the OP's pool), so the NEC's definitions of "storable pool" and "permanently installed pool" were [amended in the 2023 edition](https://iaeimagazine.org/electrical-fundamentals/permanent-or-storable-when-it-comes-to-pools-definitions-make-all-the-difference/) to fix this issue for good.

So, I'd go back to your AHJ and tell them that they can't require bonding on a storable pool, since 680.26 (the equipotential bonding section of the NEC's pool chapter) is in Part II of Article 680, while storable pools are only required to conform to Parts I and III of said Article.

Comment: Would this only be applicable to jurisdictions that have adopted 2023? Where I am, we're still on 2008, for heaven's sake!

Comment: @FreeMan -- one could make a coherent argument to an AHJ that the text in the prior editions was simply erroneous (it's similar to situations I've heard of before where there were "holes" in the Code)

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This "*Equipotential bonding is generally done to panels. Equipotential bonding is just another phrase for the normal “grounding electrodes” that your house already has."* is NOT what is being required, and is gibberish actually!

The NEC 680.26  (https://up.codes/s/equipotential-bonding) describes the water and all metal around the pool being interconnected by #8 wire that is also connected to earth in a specific way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/148510)

Comment: I have to down vote as the code may sound like gibberish if you do not understand the grounding and bonding requirements but it is not just the existing grounding electrode.

Comment: I understand my downvote, but I didn't know what else to do. I was strongly rebutting the very incorrect (yet still upvoted answer) by Harper... because I don't have the reputation points to actually comment on or downvote Harper's answer. I definitely DO know the topic of swimming pool equipotential bonding, being an EE expert designer of pool electronics. 

So, how could I have challenged Harper's answer before I am allowed to comment on it? 

Ed Beal downvoted me since I didn't help the OP directly. I would be happy if my "answer" could become a comment to Harper's uninformed answer.